# Does margin-top:auto help to auto-set my div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with height:auto, this I assume would increase the height depending on the contents. However I have another div right after this first div, with height:auto it will overlap the current div.

```css
div.footer{
    position:relative;
    width:1010px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:1px solid gray;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
```

This is my current css for the bottom div. How do I make it appear at the end of the first div, instead of overlapping?

The first div:

```css
div.mainbody5{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:1010px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:1px solid gray;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the css for the other div?

Comment: You mean sth like this http://jsfiddle.net/f7Qnr/ ?

Comment: I guess that's what he means... To bring the footer below the mainbody, its float : left must be replaced with 'clear: both;'

Comment: Quasdunk , Thanks Quasdunk the clearboth works wonder.

Comment: **@3cross** What exactly are you trying to do ? Which CSS rules are the actual ones ? These here , **or** the ones in jsfiddle ? I've just tested with your CSS here and the elements **do not** overlap each other.

Comment: @3cross http://jsfiddle.net/Hj66M/ - clear: both just clears the left and right float, so the element is taken out of the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not overlapping on jsfiddle for me, but I can still help you out. Just add this right after the first div:

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

This should add the space you're looking for between them.

This also keeps them centered on the page. ;)

Comment: actually, im hoping it to stick instead of having an empty line. However thats the cloest i can get now thanks alot!

Comment: No problem...but just for further clarification, is this what your page looks like? http://jsfiddle.net/VaK6E/